# update model after scaffolding existing database EF core 2.X

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using EF core 2.X scaffolding existing database. I have generated models classes using "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" command and it generate model classes.

Database team has change some table I have to run  "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" command again to generate model classes to pick only changes.

for example let say
I have one table called "employee" has column id, name.

I run "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" to generate models

After that I changed  employee table and add one more column called "address" in database. How can I scaffold  command to pick changes only .

Note: I know after generating models  I should use migration to change database but our db team is has changed db and unfortunately, I have to do this. and advice

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an optional parameter to the scaffolding command to update only the table you target.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DirectoryNameOfYourModels -Tables employee -f
```

If you are using .net core cli then use.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o DirectoryNameOfYourModels -t employee -f
```

Comment: HI Thanks for you reponse. When I run command using -t.

it remove all existing model classes and generate new DBcontext class with only one table.

In short. I want to include the change and leave everything as is. How can I do this using Scaffold-DbContext command

Comment: hi @itmannz providing -t with the argument which is the table name you want to update should only update that entity. It should leave everything as is as you said. It was working for me that way. You are using .net cli ? I thought you were using package manager console.

Comment: @Amir: It creates a new context file with only the seleted table(s) from your command.It does not make any difference if you using cli oder package mangager console.